# Ease-out time implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a component with a method `setPercentCompleted` which I want to call over the distance of e.g. 500 points in the course of 1 second.

To do this linear, I simply set a timer to a certain interval and call `setPercentCompleted` every time the timer fires.

How can I implement this functionality using a `ease-out` curve?

Comment: Can you explain it in more words, so we can understand more..

Comment: What is happening inside that method? Why do you need to update it 500 times in one second? Is there an animation/ui-update involved?

Comment: There is no point updating the UI 500 times in one second. The UI only updates at a maximum of 60 frames per second. I know this doesn't answer your question but change the 500 to a 60 :D

Comment: no - of course 'setPercentCompleted' is not called for every point, but at a predefined interval

Answer (score 1):

This is very much like a physics question.

You need to set off at a given "velocity" with a certain "deceleration" in order to reach a given "displacement" (1.0) within a given time (1.0 second).

The 2 numbers you need to determine are the initial velocity and the required deceleration.

Using SUVAT and substituting in s = 1 and t = 1.

You get from

```
s = ut + 1/2 * at^2
```

to

```
a = 2 - 2u
```

As long as your initial velocity (u) and the acceleration you apply (a) make this equation work then you'll get to a distance of 1 in 1 second.

You can see the effect by putting the numbers into a spreadsheet. You have to pick a value of u between 0 and 2 and this will give the required acceleration to get to 1.0 in 1 second.

You have a start value of your u amount and then accelerate it each time by your a value.

In fact, choosing a value of u between 0 and 1 will give an "ease-in" effect. Choosing a value of u between 1 and 2 will give and "ease-out" effect.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different equations for implementing an easing function. You can get some inspiration from this [JQuery easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). The [source code](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js) should be simple enough to port trivially to Objective C.